# Sending Email in PHP and Localhost

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

i've searched for hours for a solution but i just don't get it.
I'm fairly new to PHP, I'm doing a project where i need an email to be sent, the problem is that I can't figure how to do it.
Others who had the same problem, fixed it by configuring the php.ini and the sendemail.ini

This is my current code for testing:

```
<?php

$subject="Hi There!!";
$to="mygmail@gmail.com";
$body="This is a demo email sent using PHP on XAMPP";
if (mail($to,$subject,$body)){
 echo "Mail sent successfully!";
}
else{
 echo "Mail not sent!";
}

?>
```

I receive the "Mail sent successfully" but there is nothing on my inbox, not even on the spam folder.
I also tried to use PHPMailer but (like i said) im fairly new to php and i don't get how to enable it on my code.
What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/OAuth.php';
require 'PHPMailer/POP3.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

// SMTP configuration
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';
$mail->Password = '******';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'CodexWorld');
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'CodexWorld');

// Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('john@gmail.com');

// Add cc or bcc 
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

// Email subject
$mail->Subject = 'Send Email via SMTP using PHPMailer';

// Set email format to HTML
$mail->isHTML(true);

// Email body content
$mailContent = "<h1>Send HTML Email using SMTP in PHP</h1>
    <p>This is a test email has sent using SMTP mail server with PHPMailer.</p>";
$mail->Body = $mailContent;

// Send email
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

php mailer library 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

follow following link to understand php mailer 
https://www.codexworld.com/send-html-email-php-gmail-smtp-phpmailer/

directory structure

```
-root (your proj root directory from where your php file runs)
  -index.php (file with above code)
  -PHPMailer(folder contain mailer library)
     -php mailer files (go to git repo, download and copy all files from src folder)
```

Comment: Hi Rupesh, first of all i'm sorry for the two people who downvoted my post (sorry that i'm not a programming genius like you), thank you very much for your example but like i said I don't really understand how i'm supposed to install PHPMailer, sorry for being a dumbass.

Comment: OK I have updated post as tutorial (ignore these negative marks I also had -ve points today for complex question and I also got help from stack.)

Comment: Ok thank you very much Rupesh, now it's working as a charm.
Once again thank you so very much!!

Comment: cheers...enjoy coding